# ERROR HIPERVINCULO "Las directivas de su organizacion nos impiden completar esta accion por usted"

Tags: excel

Hoy me esta dando un error en Excel cuando quiero ir a un Hipervínculo que he creado para abrir una carpeta. 
he leído que tengo que poner Como navegador predeterminado Internet Explorer, ya lo tengo pero me sigue dando este error. no he cambiado nada y antes si me funcionaba.
Si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] un saludo

Comment: Luis, parece que el problema viene porque faltan algunas claves en el registro de Windows. [Sigue los pasos aquí indicados para resolverlo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/981149) y nos cuentas si ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, lo hice y no funciona, será porque yo tengo Windows 10? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto, 
tenia desinstalado el navegador Opera, pero por algún motivo no estaba bien desinstalado y hacia conflicto con el sistema.
ya funciona.
Gracias
Un saludo